# SQLite SELECT query in php only retrieves first row of database and combines numbers in wrong manner

Tags: php, sqlite

I am trying to build an HTML table from the database entries.

But for some reason the table fails, only the first element gets taken from the table called Contacts and all numbers to fill the first row from Phones table.

table contacts

```
id    firstName lastName
1     sdf       sdf
2     lala      yaya
3     hgj       kj
```

table phones

```
contact_id  number
1           34
2           654
3           345
3           455
```

retrieved results

```
firstName   lastName    number  number  number
hgj         kj          34      654     345
```

I am a little afraid about this query

```
SELECT contacts.firstName, contacts.lastName, group_concat(phones.number) as number 
FROM contacts LEFT JOIN phones WHERE contacts.id = phones.contact_id;
```

as I believe this is wrong then and only retrieves one row.

```
<?php
try
{
//open the database
    $db = new PDO('sqlite:db1.sqlite');

//now output the data to a simple HTML table...
    echo '<table id="kontaktid"><thread>';
    echo '<tr><th>Eesnimi</th><th>Perekonnanimi</th><th>Telefon</th><th>Telefon</th><th>Telefon</th></tr></thread><tbord>';
    $result = $db->query("SELECT contacts.firstName, contacts.lastName, group_concat(phones.number) as number 
FROM contacts LEFT JOIN phones WHERE contacts.id = phones.contact_id;")->fetchAll();
    foreach($result as $row)
    {
        $numbers = explode(',', trim($row['number']));
        list($first, $second, $third) = $numbers;
        echo $row['firstName'];
        echo "<tr><td>".$row['firstName']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['lastName']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$first."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$second."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$third."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }

    echo "</tbody></table>";
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    print 'Exception : ' .$e->getMessage();
}
$db = NULL;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use `group by` and `group_concat()` on the results:

```
select 
  c.firstname, c.lastname,
  group_concat(p.number) number
from contacts c inner join phones p
on p.contact_id = c.id
group by c.id, c.firstname, c.lastname
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rPbJqrAVjNb7eXZc4KubfT/0).
Results:

```
| firstname | lastname | number  |
| --------- | -------- | ------- |
| sdf       | sdf      | 34      |
| lala      | yaya     | 654     |
| hgj       | kj       | 345,455 |
```